# How do I publish an npm package with a two-factor authentication error?

Tags: npm

I just created a package called `ionic3-star-rating`.
When I run the command `npm publish`, it rejetcs with an error: *"This package requires that publishers enable TFA and provide an OTP to publish"*. But I haven't enabled TFA (on running `npm profile get`, it shows `two-factor auth = disabled`). when I run the command `npm profile disable-2fa`, it shows the message *"Two factor authentication not enabled"*.

Why does this happen?
I had to create another package to publish my latest changes.

Comment: usually this can be solved by using access token

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you inadvertently enabled per-package TFA on `ionic3-star-rating`.

Learn more about per-package TFA here: [How to require two-factor authentication for package publishing and settings modification](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/requiring-2fa-for-package-publishing-and-modification)

If you encounter this situation [please configure 2FA to edit this package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFuUz.png)

You will need an application that can generate a One Time Password, or OTP. For example, `Authy` or `Google Authenticator`, can generate one time passwords (OTP's). Learn more here:[How to Use Two-Factor Authentication](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-two-factor-authentication)